# Paypal Xclick URL to send payment now requires login?

Tags: email, url, paypal

The following link used to allow our customers to pay for an item, or amount due, without an account. We use this when we need to re-evaluate shipping costs and send an automated email to let the customer know and pay the balance due-

https://paypal.com/xclick/business=paypal@ourbusiness.com&item_name='Ordernumber'&amount='amount'

(There are values populating the '  '. )

This link now brings us to a sign in page for Paypal. After sign in, sending payment works fine. There is no "Use Credit Card Option"

*The issue is allowing those without Paypal to pay.*

In our business account settings we have enabled the "Paypal Account Optional" but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the URL method.

There are other link structures that work similarly. Some are noted in help documents, some from other users-

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=...

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=...

Donations aren't what we're going for, but it does allow for payment without an account.

So what's the new URL structure to allow customers to use a credit card to pay for an item without making an account?

Is this still possible?

Comment: Update: Paypal has informed me that this was on their end. This behavior has been corrected to alloy for Debit/Credit payment with no account. Again.